# Load Balancing with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, load-balancing

This may sound a basic question... 
But I am new to concept of load balancing and had few questions.

Scenario - I have 3 Tomcat 7 servers which I want to be load balanced.
I read few articles and saw that using Apache HTTP Server one can do this.
There exists a worker.properties file which needs to be defined with the servers you would like to load balance. Now the problem is that this needs to be done before I start the Apache HTTP Server. 
Problem - What if I want to add few more Tomcat Servers dynamically without restarting the Apache HTTP Server. Is this possible ?

Regards
Ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 7 Load Balancing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062742/tomcat-7-load-balancing)

Answer (score 1):

I spot an interesting article about Tomcat & PAAS: http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48086

You will probably find what you need in the article. It describes the mechanism to register / unregister a new node in the cluster.

HIH

Comment: If we are working on a cloud, can I do it via the cloud interface like Juju?

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTPD 2.4 supports dynamic reconfiguration of the load balancer. But use the load-balancer proxy module for this, not mod_jk.