# Tomcat 7 Load Balancing

Tags: apache, load, tomcat7, load-balancing, redhat

Looking to implement Load balancing for two Tomcat 7 instances each on a different machine & two other Tomcat 7 instances on a different machine serving two different purpose.

On Machine 1, will have two Tomcat instances TomA.1 & TomB.1 running on different ports 
On Machine2, will have two Tomcat instances TomA.2 & TomB.2 running on different ports

Now TomA.1 & TomA.2 needs to be run in LoadBalanced fashion & similarily TomB.1 & TomB.2 needs to be run in LoadBalanced fashion.

Would highly appreciate if anyone can point to the best practices & which Apache module to use as a load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod_JK is what you're looking for: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

Howto doc: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html